# Android album art thumbnails problem: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri

Tags: android

I am trying to display a list of albums (of music mp3s stored on the sd-card) along with the album art for each album. The album art is stored in the mp3s tag (it is not a separate image on the SD card)

I can get the album details fine using:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Albums._ID, Albums.ALBUM, Albums.ARTIST, Albums.ALBUM_ART, Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS };
        String rowsToReturn = null;
        String[] selectionWhere = null;
        String sortOrder = Media.ALBUM + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, rowsToReturn, selectionWhere, sortOrder);

        String albumArtUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Albums.ALBUM_ART));
```

The URI is correct, but when I try to set the URi to the src of an ImageView, I get a silent error being thrown "resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri".

```
imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(albumArtUri));
```

This only happens for some albums. Some are fine and display the album art correctly.
I took a look at the URI path and checked on the SD card for the thumbnail images and found them here: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/

I found images that work and images that dont, so the image does exist, but just cannot be read correctly. I even tried copying the images off the sd card and adding .png extension to the files - the ones that show up on the phone work, but the ones that don't are 'corrupt'

Finally I copied the mp3 files themselves back to the PC and inspected the album art embedded in the tags and they all show correctly.

It's almost as if the thumbnails that the Android system is creating form the tags are invalid or corrupt, but this can't be right.

Or maybe I need to read them differently?

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue could be with Media scanning. Delete the cache folder and open the music player app.It will create album cache again for all the songs. See if this helps.